# <li> item retrieve from database

Tags: sql, asp.net

```
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>Inbox <span class="badge" runat="server" style="color: red" id="txtContactCount">0</span> </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="getdata" runat="server">
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="Portal_noticexD.aspx">View all notifications</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

  public void binddata()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("E_R_GET101", con);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subs_cd", loggeduser.SUBSIDIARY_CD);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPLOYEE", loggeduser.EmployeeNo);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
         con.Open();
         da.Fill(dt);
        getdata.DataSource = dt;
        getdata.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
```

[image]

my stored procedure will get this data from my database,and bind to `<li>`,but fail to do so,or i need to change the method?

Comment: Yes. Yes it is. Give us some more context and we might even be able to tell you how.

Comment: for  <asp:ListBox> i am able to get the listitem from db,but li i have no idea,can you provide me some references?thx so much

Comment: you can use a simple repeater control or listview to achieve that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395019/dynamically-generated-bulleted-list-from-code-behind use bulleted list control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Repeater` control in ASP.NET web forms to create an unordered list.

**.ASPX:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ul>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                    <%# Eval("STATUS") %>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <SeparatorTemplate>
                <hr />
            </SeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ul>
</form>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public DataTable BindData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("E_R_GET101", con);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subs_cd", loggeduser.SUBSIDIARY_CD);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPLOYEE", loggeduser.EmployeeNo);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    con.Open();
    da.Fill(dt);
    Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
    //getdata.DataSource = dt;
    //getdata.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

You might also consider doing a Google search on a proper way of disposing of resources in ADO.NET by implementing a `using` statement